# How to hide and display a inputtext field on lookup value selection

Tags: visualforce

I have a vf page where I have a lookup field as User__C and a inputtext field Address__c.

I want if i select user as 'X' then Address__c should appear else remain hidden.

How can we achieve this scenario.

```
<apex:page standardController="Account" >
<apex:form >
<apex:pageBlock id="xxxpb1">

<apex:pageBlockSection>

<apex:actionRegion >               

  <apex:inputField id="xxxif1" value="{!Account.MyThunder__Account__c}" required="true" >

     <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" rerender="xxxpb1" />
  </apex:inputField>

</apex:actionRegion>

</apex:pageBlockSection>


<apex:pageBlockSection id="xxxpbs1" rendered="true">

 <apex:inputField id="xxxif2" value="{!Account.MyThunder__Business_Hours__c }" rendered="{!IF(Account.MyThunder__Account__r.Name =='United Oil & Gas Corp.',true,false)}"/>

</apex:pageBlockSection>


</apex:PageBlock>
</apex:form>    
</apex:page>
```

Regards

Comment: Idea would be to add Boolean variable in controller called IsAddressDisplayed,  then create method in apex that set this variable to true/false based on your criteria, add actionfunction, that would execute that method, on rerender put your address field, then on inputField at oncomplete add those action function. It should be working by scenario that you need

Comment: Hi .. I tried the above code.. But it is not displaying the text field...